# Are PDF files opensouce?

Tags: pdf, alternative, open-source

I was just wondering if PDF formats are opensource.

I've seen openoffice save a document in ODT format in contrast to DOC or DOCX. Is there alternate file format to PDF?

Comment: @CloseVoters: Why would this question be considered as off-topic? Don't we use pdf files in Ubuntu? The user has a question about something which he uses on Ubuntu... These have always been considered on-topic...

Comment: ODT, DOC, DOCX formats are very different beast than PDF (the latter is not designed as an editable file format). And using the "opensource" adjective for a format is quite misleading. It's more a difference between open specification and proprietary formats.

Comment: Next time when you "wonder" about something please use this excellent site called Wikipedia. [Here's the article about PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF).

Comment: @Aditya: I can't find this kind of question in the list of "allowed questions" on http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: The question is about something he uses on Ubuntu (using Ubuntu and third-party applications are completely valid)... On the other way around, there is a specific section on that link which mentions what are the topics which are categorically off-topic (using mint, backtrack, bugs, etc). Moreover this is not a question which falls under points mentioned at [help/dont-ask] for "don't ask" questions... I think I have made my point clear, if not I would request you to raise your concerns on [meta] so that we can have extended discussions.

Comment: @Aditya This is offtopic, because it is not about Ubuntu. Just because pdfs can be used on Ubuntu too it won't make it ontopic. This has nothing to do with the Ubuntu OS or something related to it. This is a general question about the PDF fileformat or about opensource. To see why your reasoning is wrong: Windows running as a guest OS on an Ubuntu machine also won't be ontopic, although a lot of Ubuntu users run windows in a VM. If the problem is with the VM then it's ontopic, if the problem is with Windows then it's offtopic. Here the question isn't about a PDF on Ubuntu so it's offtopic.

Comment: @falconer: Your metaphor about Window is totally off-the-mark... Windows is an OS in itself, if there are problems using it in a VM one would never expect them to be supported on any site that doesn't deal with Windows. Moreover, you say it's offtopic since this question isn't about PDF **on Ubuntu**. Why do you expect that we need to mention Ubuntu in the body of the question each and everytime? Isn't it a given unless there are circumstances which indicate that a contrary assumption would be more appropriate? Moreover, to discuss it further, please open a Meta question.

Comment: @Aditya *"on any site that doesn't deal with Windows"*: But if we follow your reasoning this site deals with windows in such cases. That's what I tried to mean. You said previously that there is a list *"which mentions what are the topics which are categorically off-topic"* and Windows **is not** listed there as offtopic. This question is not about Ubuntu. It's about PDF and its legal. Even if you mention that you are using Ubuntu it won't make it ontopic. It's not the problem that Ubuntu is not mentioned in the question, the problem is that the question **is not about Ubuntu**. 100% offtopic.

Comment: @Aditya I won't open a meta on this subject, because I don't really care if this question stays or goes. I just wanted to tell you that these kind of questions are offtopic. (AFAIK).

Comment: I don't see how this could be Ubuntu related...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PDF format itself is freely usable and the relevant patents can be used freely (although they apparently remain under Adobe's control so this could potentially change, IANAL regarding patent law).

> Adobe Systems made the PDF specification available free of charge in
>   1993, PDF remained a proprietary format, controlled by Adobe, until it
>   was officially released as an open standard on July 1, 2008, and
>   published by the International Organization for Standardization as ISO
>   32000-1:2008.
>
> In 2008, Adobe published a Public Patent License to ISO 32000-1
>   granting royalty-free rights for all patents owned by Adobe that are
>   necessary to make, use, sell and distribute PDF compliant
>   implementations.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format

The ODT format is part of the OpenDocument specifications, which are also free to use, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument#Licensing.

Answer (score 1):

[PDF](http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/adobepdf.html) is largely based on [PostScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript). It's very common to find graphics files and academic papers in PostScript (.ps file extension) format.

However, if you are looking for the advanced features of PDF files such as fillable forms, security signatures, and such you will not find those features in PostScript files.

The Linux/UNIX world has long had useful tools for working with PostScript files such as  [GhostScript](http://www.ghostscript.com/), which also happens to work with PDF files.